# Difference between object of the class and pointer of the class at initialization

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, reference

In C++ Suppose I have

```
class Sample{
 public:
 void someFunction();
};
```

In main() is there any difference between doing

```
Sample obj;
obj.someFunction();

AND

Sample *obj = new Sample();
obj->someFunction();
```

Is it only a matter of syntax or is there a performance/implementation difference? When should one be used over the other? Can I implement linked list using obj instead of *obj?

Comment: Missing `delete obj;` for the later.

Comment: You don't have a "pointer of the class", you have a "pointer to an *object*".

Comment: And yes there is a difference. The main difference (besides the different type of the variables `obj`) being where the object is being located. Another difference is that for the pointer you need to use *indirection* to reach the object itself from the pointer (by dereferencing the pointer).

Comment: In more concrete terms, it is the difference between *what* something is, and *where* something is.